# What's wrong with my desktop entry?

Tags: unity

I have a problem with a desktop entry, looks like is not working fine.

I want it to start a Genymotion VM.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=nexus
Comment="Nexus S, Genymotion"
Exec=./home/pablo/app/genymotion/player -n "08b6a8de-e6d1-4b9c-824c-5dffc929b9ca"
Icon=/home/pablo/app/genymotion/icons/nexus.png
Terminal=0
```

I think the Exec line may be is wrong, but I don't know if it's right.
If I put the Exec code on a terminal, It works fine.

I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: The leading `.` looks wrong to me: it makes `./home` relative to the current directory. You probably want an absolute path i.e. `/home/pablo/app/genymotion/player`

Comment: What steeldriver said, plus I believe you don't need double-quotes for the `Comment` section, and `Terminal` should be a boolean, i.e. either `true` or `false`

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the . and set the terminal=false.
Works fine =D